# Работа акселерометра в режиме сна под Android

Tags: android

При считывании данных с акселерометра внутри сервиса в режиме сна (после нажатия на кнопку питания) данные меняются не с той периодичностью, которая была задана, а лишь дважды в секунду. Есть ли возможность сохранять периодичность изменения данных в режиме сна?
P.S.: использование PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK не решило данной проблемы.